# Simple arithmetic via registers in c using custom ISR

Tags: c, assembly, cpu-registers, isr

I am writing a program in which i have to make my own ISR and do basic arithmetic like when i set AH to 1 it should add BX and CX registers. When AH is set 2 it should do subtraction on BX and CX registers.

My problem is that the result produced is not accurate.
My code is below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<io.h>
#include<bios.h>
#include<dos.h>

void interrupt (*oldint65) ();
void interrupt newint65();

int result;
void main()
{
     clrscr();


    oldint65 = getvect(0x65);
    setvect(0x65, newint65);

    _AH = 1; _BX = 4; _CX = 4;
    geninterrupt (0x65);

    printf("\nResult of addition is: %d\n", result);

    setvect(0x65, oldint65);

     getch();
}
void interrupt newint65()
{
    switch (_AH){
    case 1:
        {
            result = _BX + _CX;
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean not accurate ?

Comment: 4 + 4 = 8 and its showing only 4

Comment: Try printing value of _AH in newint65() ISR. This shall be the fiest step of debugging.

Comment: What OS is this for? And where are `_AX`, `_BX`, and `_CX` defined. Is this DOS, considering that those are 16-bit registers?